# How to use openpyxl to get the cell content via the DefinedName?

Tags: python, openpyxl

For example, the cell's coordinate is A1, setup a `DefinedName name="cat"` with `coordinate='A1'` . Then I want to read the content from `cell` via `DefinedName "cat"`. But it seems not supported. Any other methods to help? [See here for example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGFK.png)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']
cat = ws['cat'].value
```

Comment: is "cat" alias name for a particular cell (e.g. A1) or entire sheet1? - What is excel equivalent for reference?

Comment: the 'cat' is the alias name of a cell which means in Excel, the coordinate 'A1' equals to 'cat'.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `alias`. If you mean some kind of defined name then these are workbook constants.

Comment: When you select one cell in excel, on the left top corner, it'll show the coordinate of the cell, like 'A1', 'B8', etc. and you can change the 'A1' to another name like 'cat', 'dog'. So here the ````alias```` mean another definition of the coordinate of the cell.

Comment: Excel uses defined names for this. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How I found the answer**

I don't know the function of excel. So I 'named' the cell A1 as `cat` and save the file. I extracted the file through as rar file. `cat` was found in `xl/workbook.xml`, the origin content is `<definedName name="cat">工作表1!$A$1</definedName>`. It's a element called `definedName` with attribute `name`, and its content consists of worksheet's `title` and cell `coordinate`. So the function is called `defined name` or something related. I found it in [official doc](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/defined_names.html)

**Answer**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")

# get DefinedNameList instance
defined_names_cat = wb.defined_names['cat']

# get destinations which is a generator
destinations_cat = defined_names_cat.destinations  
values = {}
for sheet_title, coordinate in destinations_cat:
    values.update({sheet_title: wb[sheet_title][coordinate].value})
my_value = values.get('Sheet1')
```

Comment: Hi aishenghuomeidaoli, after I tried the code, it works. This is want I wanted, fantastic, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Eric.K.K I'm a green hand, it's my pleasure to help and I'm very happy, too!