# How to use Excel defined names in Python to obtain the values?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have the following set of code which is trying to find the text in a cell within an excel worksheet called 'Input'. I am using openpyxl.

The cell uses a defined name in excel called 'Rperiod'. I can call the text by specifying the sheet and cell range directly, but I'm wondering if there is a way to use the defined_names function to keep it dynamic.

```
Rperiod = wb.defined_names['Rperiod']
Rperiod.value
```

This results in 'Input!$F$8' but then I can't workout if it is possible to use this result to get the text. The static method is:

```
input_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Input')

Rperiod_cell = input_sheet['F8']

Rperiod_cell.value
```

This returns the correct result 'Quarterly' but I obviously want to do this without directly specifying the cell 'F8' or the sheet 'Input'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: did you try `wb[Rperiod.value]`.value?

Comment: Does [How to use openpyxl to get the cell content via the DefinedName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848576/how-to-use-openpyxl-to-get-the-cell-content-via-the-definedname) answer the question?

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the response. The first doesn't but I'll take a look at the other question.